# Discord Bot JDA - Want to get the size of all online members

Tags: java, discord, bots

I am writing an private Discord Bot for my server with the JDA api. My bot switches his status random and one of the random events is: "playing x online"

And I want to get just the number of how many people are online at the moment no matter in what role they are, but it's not working. First it showed 1 now 2 and they are like 10-20 online. The Bot has it's own Bot role and I gave him every other role to, because I thought that will fix it, but it doesn't.

```
String[] status = new String[] {"Baba Bot", "Bester Bot", "Coolster Bot", "%members online!"};
int next = 5;

public void onSecond() {
    if(next <= 0) {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int i = rnd.nextInt(status.length);
        
        shardMan.getShards().forEach(jda -> {
            String text = status[i].replaceAll("%members", "" + jda.getUsers().size());
            
            jda.getPresence().setActivity(Activity.playing(text));
        });
        next = 5;
    } else {
        next--;
    }
}
```

That's the code I have for this. Everything works perfect besides the jda.getUsers thing. I think it is maybe because it only looks for persons in their main role, but i had 1 that could be it, but now i have constantly 2. The bot is listed in my BOT role and they are 2 other bots in their, but with my bot 3. So this don't make much sense either. Or if it matter than i have no solution of fixing it. I googled much about this and the docs too, but can't find an solution.

Would be nice if someone could help me with it ^^

LG Sören

Answer (score 0):

To get the online count of a guild/server you can use [Guild#retrieveMetaData](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Guild.html#retrieveMetaData()).

Example:

```java
guild.retrieveMetaData()
  .map(Guild.MetaData::getApproximatePresences)
  .map(count -> Activity.playing(count + " members online"))
  .queue(activity -> jda.getPresence().setActivity(activity));
```

Getting a global count would require caching all online members, which requires the privileged intent [GUILD_PRESENCES](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/requests/GatewayIntent.html#GUILD_PRESENCES). Read more about intents and member caching [in the wiki](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/Gateway-Intents-and-Member-Cache-Policy).

Personally, I don't think this is a very useful metric to display though as it requires a lot of effort to acquire for an information that is either useless (such as a global online member count) or already visible to users (in the member list).